# Computer Power Adapter Proper Volts No Amps

Tags: dc, ac-dc

I have a 4 month old laptop. The other day it stopped charging. When I meter it shows 19.94 volts and 0.0 amps. Specs call for 19.5 volts and 2.31 amps. So the manufacturer (HP) is sending me a new power supply.

However what I wanted to do was see if I can repair the old one and have a spare. Ideally leave on at the office for those frequent occurrences when I take off in a hurry and forget it.

I'm not really sure what to check first. Should I check the output just past the rectifier bridge...or perhaps trace the circuit backward from the output and see if a resistor etc. has blown?

Thought, advice, suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you try to avoid passing out upon seeing the circuitry inside.

Comment: How did you measure amps? If you just connected your meter (set to amps) across the power-supply output, you just shorted out the power-supply. You read zero because either the power-supply shut down due to the overload or because you blew the fuse in your meter! The proper way to measure current is to put the meter in series between the power-supply and the load (your laptop).

Comment: @DoxyLover it is very unlikely to be a short. Every DMM I have worked with has one set of terminals for ~0 ohm input impedance (current measurement) and a different set for mega ohm input impedance (voltage measurement).

Comment: @sam - ok, that's another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "meter it" what load did it have? 0.0 A makes no sense. Did you just take a DMM plug it in to the supply and put it in current mode and voltage mode because that would have either shorted the supply when in current mode, or more likely been meaningless because you needed to change terminals on the DMM for the current meter to work. It sounds like you did because you got no current and a slightly high voltage.

Be warned in current mode a DMM looks like a short so you need to have some other load, like a 8.441558441558442 ohm, 45.045 Watt resistor to do a real test.

It's a SMPS so its' going to be pretty complex, there probably isn't a blown resistor it's more likely a capacitor or IC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To avoid passing out I'll take my newbie questions elsewhere.

Comment: ... why 8.441558441558442? Oddly specific.

Comment: @immibis 19.5/2.31